# How save image with colorbar using imsave?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I'm wondering if there is a way to save an image using `plt.imsave()` with the colorbar.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imsave("out.jpg", img)
```

I know it is possible use `plt.colorbar()` and than save the figure with `plt.savefig()` but I have noticed `plt.savefig()` is much slower than `plt.imsave()`, and I am looking for the performance.

Comment: `imsave` saves the array with a colormap applied. It does not allow to add a colorbar or ticks, axes, etc. This is precisely the reason it is faster, because all the axes creations and transforms do not apply. If you need a colorbar, you need to go through creating a figure, placing an `imshow` and a `colorbar` and then `savefig` the figure.